# R: change colors across bars in stacked bar chart

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

Using base graphics, I got a barchart like this one

```
a <- c(1,2,3); b <- c(1,1,1)
barplot(rbind(a,b), col=c("red","gray"))
```

[image]

with each bar grey at the top and red at the bottom. However, I would like each bar to change the color at the bottom and keep the grey at the top.

```
cols <- c(rbind(c("red","green","blue"),"gray"))
barplot(rbind(a,b), col=cols)
```

did not do the trick. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way but this works.

```
a<-c(1,1,1)
b<-c(1,0,0)
c<-c(0,2,0)
d<-c(0,0,3)

cols <-c("red","green","blue","gray")
# notice order of rbind... a is last
barplot(rbind(b,c,d,a), col=cols )
```

[image]